# A preconditioner for self-consistent iteration

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-physics, iterative-method, eigensystem

I tried to derive a preconditioner for self-consistent iteration similar
to section IX in [arXiv:0804.2583](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2583).
For simplicity, consider here only
one orbital (one or two electrons) systems.

Suppose that the iteration starts with function $f_1$ and write
$f_1 = \psi_0 + \Delta \psi_0$, where $\psi_0$ is the normalized
exact solution of the Schrödinger equation. Suppose also that
$H$ is real and Hermitian, $H \psi_0 = E \psi_0$, and $\psi_0$ and
$\Delta \psi_0$ are real. Assume that $\Delta \psi_0$ is small.

Define $\Lambda := \left< f_1 \vert H f_1 \right>$ and
$g := H f_1 - \Lambda f_1$. We have
$$\Lambda = E + 2 \left< H \psi_0 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right>
+ \left< \Delta \psi_0 \vert H \Delta \psi_0 \right>$$
and we approximate
$$
\Lambda \approx E + 2 \left< H \psi_0 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> .
$$
We have
$$
g = E \psi_0 + H \Delta \psi_0 - \Lambda \psi_0 - \Lambda \Delta \psi_0
$$
from which it follows that
$$
(H - \Lambda) \Delta \psi_0 = (\Lambda - E) \psi_0 + g
\approx 2 \left< H \psi_0 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> \psi_0 + g
\tag{1}
$$
We have
\begin{eqnarray}
2 \left< H \psi_0 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> \psi_0
& = & 2( f_1 - \Delta \psi_0) \left< H(f_1 - \Delta \psi_0) \vert \Delta
\psi_0 \right> \nonumber \\
& = & 2( f_1 - \Delta \psi_0)
\left( \left< H f_1 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> -
\left< H \Delta \psi_0 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> \right) \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
and we approximate
$$
2 \left< H \psi_0 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> \psi_0
\approx
2 \left< H f_1 \vert \Delta \psi_0 \right> f_1
$$
We define linear function $G$ by
$$
G(x) := 2 \left< H f_1 \vert x \right> f_1 .
$$
Now it follows from equation (1) that
$$
(H - \Lambda - G) \Delta \psi_0 \approx g
$$
Consequently we approximate $\Delta \psi_0$ by
$$
\tilde{g} := (H - \Lambda - G)^{-1} g
$$
and set
$$
f_2 := \frac{f_1 - \tilde{g}}{\Vert f_1 - \tilde{g} \Vert}
$$
for the next iteration.
Unless we have an one electron system we also compute the new Hartree
potential and the new Hamiltonian operator for the next iteration.

I tried this method for the hydrogen atom and the hydrogen molecule.
For hydrogen atom I computed the approximate wavefunction with Arnoldi
method and then tried to enhance the result with this method. The
iteration converged well until both the gradient norm and quantity
$\Vert H \psi - E \psi \Vert$ were about $4 \cdot 10^{-15}$ and then
stopped converging.
For hydrogen molecule I computed the initial orbitals with Arnoldi method
setting Hartree potential to zero. The SC iteration converged well
until the gradient norm was about $10^{-4}$ and
$\Vert H \psi - E \psi \Vert \approx 10^{-6}$. After that the SC
iteration stopped converging.

Q: Is the derivation of the preconditioner correct?

Q: Is there some reason why the method does not work when the iteration gets close to a self-consistent solution?

Comment: Isn't $10^{-15}$ enough?

Comment: Yes, but $10^{-6}$ is not enough for the hydrogen molecule.